# How to set StompSubProtocolHandler at XML?

Tags: websocket, spring-websocket

My problem is I don't know how i set StompSubProtocolHandler at XML

I try and know normal websocket set

```
<websocket:handlers allowed-origins="*">
         <websocket:mapping path="/raphaServerHandler.do" handler="raphaServerHandler"/>
   </websocket:handlers>
```

But I need to know setting StompSubProtocolHandler at XML!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is done automatically by the:

```
<websocket:message-broker application-destination-prefix="/app">
    <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/foo" />
    <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/topic" />
</websocket:message-broker>
```

---

```
<xsd:documentation><![CDATA[
Configures broker-backed messaging over WebSocket using a higher-level messaging sub-protocol.
Registers a SimpleUrlHandlerMapping and maps paths to registered Controllers.

A StompSubProtocolHandler is registered to handle various versions of the STOMP protocol.

See EnableWebSocketMessageBroker javadoc for information on code-based alternatives to enabling broker-backed messaging.
        ]]></xsd:documentation>
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-enable

Comment: I know setting Socket Stomp but Your sample code need contoller and MessageMapping but StompSubProtocol dont have MessageMapping

Comment: Not sure how `@MessageMapping` is related to your question. The `StompSubProtocolHandler` is populated in the `MessageBrokerBeanDefinitionParser`. The `@MessageMapping` is done automatically then.

Comment: Ah... Sorry. and Thank you. In fact I don't know channel and in-out bound concept of websocket.. Do you have any sample code.. ? about stompSubProtocol?

Comment: Try investigate this application: https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio

Comment: Hi @ArtemBilan Could you please take a look at my similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55519260/error-handling-while-using-stomp-simple-broker