# Error handling while using STOMP simple broker

Tags: spring, spring-websocket, stomp, spring-messaging

I am creating simple STOMP broker using `@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker`. When `RuntimeException` happens in `@MessageMapping` method I would like to receive STOMP `ERROR` frame, but it doesn't work like that by default.

It seems that `ERROR` frame is not supported in simple broker:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-messaging/src/main/java/org/springframework/messaging/simp/SimpMessageType.java#L28-L44

On the other hand, there is a mechanism to send `ERROR` frames already available in `spring-websocket` and its code references some classes which are related to simple broker:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-websocket/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/socket/messaging/StompSubProtocolHandler.java#L349

How to enable mechanism of sending `ERROR` frames when `RuntimeException` happens in `@MessageMapping` method?

Answer (score 0):

Quick and easy way to do this is to have a specific error handler subscription on the client that subsribes before making any calls to the @MessageMapping endpoints.  Then wrap all calls to the method in your websocket server with a try catch block and handle the exceptions that occur.  Then its a simple case of doing something like:

```
messagingTemplate.convertAndSend( "/topic/clientControl/1234", "SHUT_DOWN"); (or send to user etc, depends on your subscription model)
```

You can either send an error message to the client and allow it to handle it or decide what to do server side and have a control subscription allowing the server to pass commands to the client.

Comment: Hi, I tried that, but it's sending MESSAGE frame and I would like to achieve sending ERROR frame which is part of STOMP standard.